# Perl mechanize Find all links array loop issue

Tags: perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize

I am currently attempting to create a **Perl webspider using WWW::Mechanize.**

What I am trying to do is **create a webspider that will crawl the whole site** of the URL (entered by the user) and extract all of the links from every page on the site.

**But I have a problem with how to spider the whole site to get every link, without duplicates**
What I have done so far (the part im having trouble with anyway):

```
foreach (@nonduplicates) {   #array contain urls like www.tree.com/contact-us, www.tree.com/varieties....
$mech->get($_);
my @list = $mech->find_all_links(url_abs_regex => qr/^\Q$urlToSpider\E/);  #find all links on this page that starts with http://www.tree.com

#NOW THIS IS WHAT I WANT IT TO DO AFTER THE ABOVE (IN PSEUDOCODE), BUT CANT GET WORKING
#foreach (@list) {
#if $_ is already in @nonduplicates
#then do nothing because that link has already been found
#} else {
#append the link to the end of @nonduplicates so that if it has not been crawled for links already, it will be
```

**How would I be able to do the above?**

**I am doing this to try and spider the whole site to get a comprehensive list of every URL on the site, without duplicates.**

If you think this is not the best/easiest method of achieving the same result I'm open to ideas.

**Your help is much appreciated, thanks.**

Comment: >> Each of the links returned is a WWW::Mechanize::Link object.

Comment: better to make nonduplicates to be hash, loop with it using keys, make url to be  a key

Comment: could you show me some example code to explain what you means, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hash to track which links you've seen before and put any unseen ones onto `@nonduplicates` for processing:

```
$| = 1;
my $scanned = 0;

my @nonduplicates = ( $urlToSpider ); # Add the first link to the queue.
my %link_tracker = map { $_ => 1 } @nonduplicates; # Keep track of what links we've found already.

while (my $queued_link = pop @nonduplicates) {
    $mech->get($queued_link);
    my @list = $mech->find_all_links(url_abs_regex => qr/^\Q$urlToSpider\E/);

    for my $new_link (@list) {
        # Add the link to the queue unless we already encountered it.
        # Increment so we don't add it again.
        push @nonduplicates, $new_link->url_abs() unless $link_tracker{$new_link->url_abs()}++;
    }
    printf "\rPages scanned: [%d] Unique Links: [%s] Queued: [%s]", ++$scanned, scalar keys %link_tracker, scalar @nonduplicates;
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%link_tracker);
```

Comment: oops, that was an error. I've edited to fix it. You'll also need to populate `@nonduplicates` with something, this can just be the starting url (see edit also).

Comment: Thanks a lot,that works a treat. If i wanted to simply print out every link that it has found, or save them to a file what would be the best way of doing it?

Comment: Also I have found an issue whereby if there is an error GETing the url it fails and quits what it is doing e.g for http:/www.prodirectsoccer.com, thanks

Comment: @perl-user use `$mech->success` to see if the `get` failed and move onto the `next` link. See: http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Esuccess%28%29

Comment: I have it working correctly now, thanks a lot. One thing I am trying to change is the print output. I am trying to print every link found in a nice list down the page (or to a text file) with only the url (not the '$VAR1 = {'http:/www.poshbox.co.uk => 48,') you get with Data::Dumper but cant get the syntax right when dealing with %link_tracker to print it how i explained above?

Comment: @perl-user, if you just want to print the urls, you can get them with `keys %link_tracker` then loop through.

Comment: I have used 'foreach $linksL (keys %link_tracker) {
print "$linksL => $link_tracker{$linksL}\n";' which does give me a list of the URL's but the '=> and a number' is still appended to the end of each one?

Comment: Then remove the `=> $link_tracker{$linksL}` from your print.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, realised once id sent it. I'm adding the error checking part so that it doesnt just kill the script when it finds a 404 and so on. I know the code I need if (mech->status != 200) { do something };  or $mech->success but whats the best way of getting it to move to the next link without dieing?

Comment: I was wondering whether I could ask a follow up question about this. I am trying to use Parallel::ForkManager (which I have used many times before) to speed up the crawling/getting of the webpages but it just will not work, I was wondering whether you could help at all please, it would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;
...

my @list = $mech->find_all_links(...);

my @unique_urls = uniq( map { $_->url } @list );
```

Now `@unique_urls` contains the unique urls from `@list`.